# Bootstrap hide tooltip when clicking on a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

How can I hide a tooltip() on click? Check my code to understand more clearly.

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tab"]').tooltip();
});
```

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/e45ggmrb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooltips have a `tooltip` class, so you can access it by it's class and use `.hide()`:

```
$('[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(){
    $(".tooltip").hide();
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use the built-in method, `.tooltip('hide')` for hiding the tooltips? Also, this would hide all tooltips (which might be fine).

Comment: @JoshCrozier Because that method actually has a unintended problem, once hidden when it toggles display again it doesn't get hidden, that's why. I'd say it's fine since there is only one tooltip shown at a time in this example. This method hides the tooltip and keeps it hidden.

Comment: Good point. I didn't realize that's what the OP wanted. It wasn't stated in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the [`shown.bs.tab` event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs-events) to determine when a tab is clicked, then you can access the clicked tab, `e.target`, and hide the corresponding tooltip:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/d036g0bf/)

```
$('[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $(e.target).siblings('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying so promptly. Your solution has 1 problem. The tooltip has disappeared, but when I hover a tab, it's stays display again.